# Devices w/o major numbers

Tags: linux, kernel, driver

I was wondering how hardware devices w/o major numbers (drivers) work with linux kernel. For instance ls -l will show a minor number for my dvd player but it won't have a major number. I wondered why.

Comment: I'm *pretty* sure you're mistaken...

Answer (score 0):

Devices that have minor numbers have major numbers. Please post the output of the `ls -l` that you are referring to (is that really so hard to include with a question?) Not everyone has your exact kernel, distro, version of GNU coreutils, or the driver whose node you are looking at.